# Using Angular's orderBy filter with a function that has parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I have an array of objects where most of the parameters are functions that are passed different parameters. Is it possible to use Angular's orderBy filter with these properties? One variation of what I've tried that's not working:

```
<tr ng-repeat="warrior in warriors | orderBy: dps(vm.orderTarget)">
    <td>{{warrior.name}}</td>
    <td>{{warrior.dps(vm.target1)}}</td>
    <td>{{warrior.dps(vm.target2)}}</td>
    <td>{{warrior.dps(vm.target3)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is `vm`? Can you explain it more?

Comment: Most best practices say to use controllerAs and never $scope, and vm is a very common default for controllerAs, standing for 'view model.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tricky solution:

```
<tr ng-attr-temp="{{warrior.temp=warrior.dps(vm.orderTarget)}}" ng-repeat="warrior in warriors | orderBy: 'temp'">
    <td>{{warrior.name}}</td>
    <td>{{warrior.dps(vm.target1)}}</td>
    <td>{{warrior.dps(vm.target2)}}</td>
    <td>{{warrior.dps(vm.target3)}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Like a charm, thanks. Now to see how to change the sorting stat and reverse them!